# small hole in A/C condenser for 98 blazer

Tags: troubleshooting

I have a 98 chevy blazer 4dr. the A/C system in my truck is brand new, every last part of it. before i got hit, my a/c blew soo cold it was like being in a freezer room. when i got hit, it formed a small dent in the condenser in the lower passenger side, and now there are just a few very small holes in the condenser.

my thoughts are to use JB weld on the front and back of the holes then buy the recharge kit with the dye in it and get the UV light and see if the JB weld sealed the holes and my A/C system holds a charge.

i was just wondering if anyone has done something like this and has any input/hints/tips to give me or to tell me that its just not worth my time because it wont work...

i also aready have a replacement condenser but i am hopeing that the jb weld will work and i can return the condenser because lately i have been too busy with other things and a bit lazy when i do have free time to just replace the condenser...lol

thanks for you time and i hope that the responces that i get tell me that the JB weld will work and i can return the other one i got for the "just in case"

Answer (score 3):

The internal holes in the condenser are very small and damage to part of it will impede optimal flow.  Now it sounds like the damage might not be that widespread and your AC system strong enough to handle a weakened leak.  However, in your situation, I would just replace the condenser and not have to spend the time worrying about leaks.

Also, I would **strongly** suggest getting the system evacuated and charged by someone who has the tools because just adding refrigerant with the moisture and air that is now in your system is not good for your compressor or the rest of your system.

Comment: I agree. I've successfully repaired radiator leaks like this with JB Weld, but I don't think you'd have much success on an AC condenser. The system pressure is MUCH higher and the consequences of a leak are more severe: R-134a, not to mention R-12 in older vehicles, is a lot more expensive than antifreeze, and if air or water leaks *into* the system you'll damage your whole AC system.